# header fix on scroll to particular position

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a web page where i want to fix a div to top of i scroll the window to that div and release fix position if i scroll above that div but i am facing a problem the div is not getting fixed when i reach there

here is my code

**jquery**

```
var customerBillHeadPos = $('.customer_bills_head').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(windowPos>=customerBillHeadPos){
        $('.customer_bills_head').addClass('position_fixed');
    } else {
        $('.customer_bills_head').removeClass('position_fixed');
    };
});
```

**CSS**

```
.customer_bills_head.position_fixed{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 70px;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I checked your code and it is actually working, so check your console logs, maybe some other scripts are messing this up. Check if jquery is loaded properly and you don't have conflicts. Firebug or browser developer tools and console will help.

Also check other styles that could be messing it up.

I only added 200px margin top for .customer_bills_head, and margin-top:0; when you reach it, and some styles for simulation.

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    background: url("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT7vR66BWT_HdVJpwxGJoGBJl5HYfiSKDrsYrzw7kqf2yP6sNyJtHdaAQ");
    height:2000px;
}

h1{
  color:white;
}
.customer_bills_head{
  width:100%;
  height:110px;
  margin-top:200px;
  background: #666
}
.customer_bills_head.position_fixed{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 9;
    margin-top:0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/syLdLeet/2/

Comment: got the solution...when i am writing this script in load function its working perfectly